# Finding Weibull parameters based on KM curve provided in a paper

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution, kaplan-meier

I need to estimate parameters for a weibull (or any other appropriate function) based on Kaplan-Meier curves and confidence intervals found in research papers. See figure 3 in this paper as an example: https://clinicalsarcomaresearch.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13569-019-0114-5 .

My goal is to

1. determine the survival function based on a few different papers
2. weight the resulting parameters based on other information (e.g., knowledge that a study was very small or that the design likely resulted in optimistic or pessimistic results)
3. use the final parameters to do a monte carlo simulation

What would be a preferred methodology for accomplishing this?

My initial thought is to manually take points from the provided survival function, use those to fit a weibull, fine-tune by looking at graph and adjusting parameters or adding more data points. This methodology unfortunately doesn't take into account that I often have median values and confidence intervals.

Note: I am programming in python

Comment: Would you be able to summarize the sort of information or data you have to work with? It seems it includes medians.

Comment: Sure. There are almost always survival probabilities (in the form of a Kaplan Meier curve, not a table),  and the median survival. Additionally, there are often there are confidence intervals, qualitative info about censoring, and sometimes even quantitative censoring info.